# Let $X$ be a normal Hausdorff space ($T_4$ space) with a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of clopen sets. What is the pointwise closure of the following family

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a topological space which is $T_4$ and its topology has a basis $\mathcal{B}$ consisting of clopen subsets. Let $\mathcal{F}=\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid B\in \mathcal{B}\}$ be the family of characteristic functions of the basic clopen elements of the topology. I want to compute the pointwise closure of $\mathcal{F}$ in the set $\{0,1\}^X=\{f \mid f:X\to \{0,1\}\}$ . I claim that the pointwise closure of $\mathcal{F}$ is the whole $\{0,1\}^X$.

My proof: Take an arbitrary $f\in \{0,1\}^X$. We need to show that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n\in X$ there exists some $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $f(x_i)=\mathbb{1}_B(x_i)$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Let $x_1\dots,x_n\in X$ be arbitrary points such that $f(x_i)=1$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ and let $y_1\dots,y_m\in X$ be arbitrary points such that $f(y_j)=0$ for all $j=1,\dots,m$. As $X$ is Hausdorff, points are closed. Hence, the sets $\{x_i: i=1,\dots,n\}$ and $\{y_j: j=1,\dots,m\}$ are disjoint closed sets. By the normality of $X$ there exists some disjoint open subsets $U,V$ such that $\{x_i: i=1,\dots,n\}\subseteq U$ and $\{y_j: j=1,\dots,m\}\subseteq V$. By the existence of the basis of clopen sets, we can also assume $V=U^c$ and hence $\mathbb{1}_U$ agrees with $f$ in $x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $\mathcal{B}$ to be essentially *all* clopen subsets of $X$. In that case it's indeed not hard to find one member $\mathbb{1}_B$ for some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $B$ contains some finite subset of $X$ while missing some other disjoint finite subset of $X$, which is in essence what is needed to show $\mathcal{F}$ to be dense. In fact it's enough for $\mathcal{B}$ to be a clopen base closed under finite unions for this, plus the Hausdorffness (normality is overkill).

Without it, $\mathcal{F}$ might have a smaller closure: e.g. take $X=\Bbb N$ (discrete so $T_4$ for sure) and $\mathcal{B} = \{\{n\}\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$, which is clopen base. Then the closure of $\mathcal{F}$ in $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is essentially all infinite "unit vectors" plus the "zero-vector", a convergent sequence in essence, and not all of the cube.